# AspNet 5 to service fabric

Tags: asp.net, owin, azure-service-fabric

How to deploy a normal AspNet 5 application to Service Fabric cluster? Its an existing ASPNet5 application, and not create as a ServiceFabric ASPNet5 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your ASPNET5 application is self-hosted using Owin/Kestrel. IIS is not supported or does not work in in Service Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

SF now support Docker Compose. So you can take an existing IIS web application and host it in SF.